# Changing content of a button in one window, depending on which button was clicked in another window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to set the content of one  button and one textbox, from multiple possible ones, in a window `Window1` based on which button I click in a window `Window2`.

Opening `Window2` from `Window1` `

```
private void myContentSetter(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           Window2 h = new Window2();
           h.Show();
        //set content of the button which triggered this listener and an associated textbox
        }
```

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach I can think of is to pass a single class to each and every form that will act as the ViewModel and use [WPF Data Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.100).aspx) to control the behaviour of the forms.

[Scott Logic](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/04/05/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-databinding-in-wpf-silverlight-and-wp7-part-one.html) also has quite a good example on how you can create your classes to bind.